# Weird compilation error in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c, visual-studio

I have a problem compiling the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int main () {
    printf("short: [%d,%d]\n",SHRT_MIN,SHRT_MAX);
    printf("int: [%d, %d]\n",INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
    printf("long: [%d, %d]\n",LONG_MIN,LONG_MAX);
    int aa=017;
    printf("%d\n",aa);
    return 0;
}
```

Error message is:

```
1>c:\tic\ex1\ex2\ex2.c(12) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'
1>c:\tic\ex1\ex2\ex2.c(13) : error C2065: 'aa' : undeclared identifier
```

However, compilation for this is fine:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <limits.h>
    int main () {
        int aa=017;
        printf("short: [%d,%d]\n",SHRT_MIN,SHRT_MAX);
        printf("int: [%d, %d]\n",INT_MIN, INT_MAX);
        printf("long: [%d, %d]\n",LONG_MIN,LONG_MAX);
        printf("%d\n",aa);
        return 0;
    }
```

Any idea what the issue is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C, variables previously had to be declared at the top of the scope, before any code is executed. This isn't the case in C99 (which Visual Studio doesn't implement.)

Comment: I'm not sure if that restriction was removed earlier than C99.

Comment: C89 (aka C90) requires declarations to appear at the top of a block, but not necessarily function. Many compilers support declarations anywhere as an extension but this definitely isn't C90.

Comment: if you tell the VC++ compiler to compile C code (and not C++) code it will default to an archaic profile of C (possibly older than C89). Just let the compiler compile C++, if you want to trim down the code generated use compiler switches --  for example disabling the exception mechanism and such.

Answer (score 3):

Visual Studio doesn't support C99 so all declarations (such as for `aa` in your example) in a block must appear before any statements (such as your `printf` calls).

Answer (score 1):

In (old) C, you cannot declare a variable anywhere as you can in C++ or in the latest C standards. You have to declare it directly after the open curly brace of a scope, as in your second example.

Answer (score 1):

In "classic" C language (C89/90) declarations are not allowed to appear in the middle of the code. Your original declaration of `aa` would be valid in C++ or in the "new" C (C99), but not in C89/90.

VS 2008 comes with the C89/90 compiler, which is why you get these errors.

On top of that, the proper `printf` format specifier for priting `long` values is `%ld`, not `%d`.

Answer (score 1):

In C prior to C99, all variables in a given scope have to be defined before other statements in that scope. Though it initially looks the same, this isn't *quite* the same as GMan's answer. In particular, a function can contain other blocks that define other scopes, and those can define variables after executable statements in the outer block:

```
int main() { 
    int x;

    printf("whatever");
    int y; // not allowed

    { 
         int z;    // allowed
    }
    return 0;
}
```

While defining a block like this (that's not associated with any flow control like an if statement or while loop) is fairly uncommon, it *is* allowed as a part of C.

Answer (score 0):

change the file type to cpp then it will work (and you can add c++ to your resume)

Comment: I sure hope people can't add languages on resumes by renaming files. :)

Comment: there's more to that actually, change stdio to cstdio, add using namespace std; but anyway, I'm just learning C for fun.

Comment: nope - all else will compile fine, no need for cstdio, namespace or anything

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly tell it to compile as C, doesn;t visual studio compile .c files as c++ anyway?
You can certainly use // commnets